# Why would I use Windows Live Mesh to remote into a computer instead of regular RDC?

Tags: windows-live-mesh

The question says it all.

I don't really understand what **benefit** there is to Mesh over RDC.

Their feature set seems to be very similar, so I'm not quite sure why MS would produce two sets of software that accomplish the same goal.

Comment: I would suggest you put more into your question. This is not a discussion forum and we encourage users to post more detailed questions. Maybe explain what you understand RDC as being.

Comment: @Diago RDC as in the default connection protocol that comes with Windows. Juding from Meshes site it didn't look much different, but Wil answered my question perfectly.  I don't intend for my question to open up a discussion, it was just a concise question.

Comment: I think you missed my point. Instead of commenting, edit your question and add some more detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple, in most situations, you won't need to touch your firewall.

Remote Desktop is a full on remote computing solution - Printer and device sharing, Folder sharing, Sound forwarding and a few more... In later versions it can even do high definition streaming!

On the other hand, Mesh is very scaled back - but it does not require any port forwarding or special configuration apart from the initial installation. Then, as long as you have an outgoing internet connection, you can interact with the desktop.

Comment: Very cool. How is the performance compared to RDC?

Comment: @Joseph depends on the internet speed, however, I believe that RDC is faster.

Comment: Edited to explain differences a bit better.

Comment: IIRC, another difference is that you will need user credentials to log into Remote Desktop, while you get the Welcome Screen when you use the Mesh remote thing.

Comment: Agree with Wil. Live mesh desktop has gotten me out of trouble many times when I need to make an urgent fix, and all I have to work with is an Internet Cafe....;)